# C# base class has an enum property that is unknown

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to have the following structure. Now this code is more a concept but what I want is the base class to have some generic type that holds an actual enum representation.

I know this code doesn't work but trying to achieve the following below.

The abstract class is coming from another assembly and doesn't have access to the DaysOfWeek enum

```
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
   S, M, T, W
}

public abstract class Base
{
   public abstract Enum SomeUnknownEnum { get; }

   public abstract void Foo(Enum unknown);
}

public class Derived : Base
{
   // I know this does not work and it should Enum for this to compile but this is the end goal
   public override DaysOfWeek SomeUnknownEnum { get; }

   public override void Foo(DaysOfWeek unknown)
   {
        switch(unknown)
        {
           //...
        } 
   }
}
```

Comment: `class HasGenericEnum<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum { public TEnum Value { get; } }`.

Comment: casting enums to ints and back might help with this

Comment: ...but because enum types are value-types, not reference-types, they cannot participate in _return-type covariance_ (or _parameter type contravariance_) so you can't do this in an `abstract` class situation.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Unfortunately you can't use the cast operator with `struct, Enum`-constrained generic types - you either have to do an ugly boxing-cast - or use runtime `IL.Emit` to generate type-safe conversion functions (painful, but worth the effort!)

Comment: @Dai I think you are right here since the enum is value type...this is unfortunate as the consumer of the abstract class will have enums they have to declare on their side. I could also make them int and cast like Neville suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic type limited to Enums:

```cs
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    S, M, T, W
}

public abstract class Base<T> where T : Enum
{
    public abstract T SomeUnknownEnum { get; }
    public abstract void Foo(T unknown);
}

public class Derived : Base<DaysOfWeek>
{
    public override DaysOfWeek SomeUnknownEnum { get; }
    public override void Foo(DaysOfWeek unknown)
    {
        switch (unknown)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having an abstract `SomeUnknownEnum` and then overriding here is pointless: `Base<DaysOfWeek>.SomeUnknownEnum ` has type DaysOfWeek already: you don't need to override to go from `System.Eenum` to a specific enum type.